# Count non-nan-values in 3d numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of N 2d numpy arrays, all of the same size Mx3, all of which represent a single sample of M coordinates. Sometimes the value of a coordinate can be np.nan.

I (think I) know how to compute the average and standard deviation over these coordinate samples, namely as follows (i.e. stack them and compute the average and std along axis=0):

```
averaged = np.nanmean(np.array(listOf2dArrays, dtype=np.float64), axis=0)

std      = np.nanstd( np.array(listOf2dArrays, dtype=np.float64), axis=0)
```

**How can I determine the *count* on which the average and std values for each coordinate are based i.e. the number of non-nan values for each coordinate(component) *m*?**

The result should be a 2d-array of dimensions Mx3 containing non-nan-count values.

Comment: Could you include an example list of arrays that need to be processed, along with the expected results?

Comment: `np.count_nonzero(~np.isnan(np.array(listOf2dArrays, dtype=np.float64)), axis=0)`

Comment: @Stef Thanks, got to the same conclusion after thinking a bit more along the lines of the avg and std code. Nice one-liner.Any advice on processing this result further to a 1d array containing the counts when they are all equal along a row? I.e. which contains the value in case of equality accross a row or np.nan otherwise. I currently solved this using a for-loop accross the rows and check using np.all(count_xyz[i]==count_xyz[i][0])

Comment: @Stef If you make your comment an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it the same way using [`count_nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html) (which is [preferred](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8913) over `sum`):

```
np.count_nonzero(~np.isnan(np.array(listOf2dArrays, dtype=np.float64)), axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a mask array and just sum 0s and 1s, where 0 either means a real value or nan value.

Basically, let us assume you have a 3D array with some random nan-values and let us count the number of nans along some axis (in your case the axis 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython
# ----------------------------
import numpy as np

nx,ny,nz=50,50,50;npts=nx*ny*nz

n_nans=100
# ----------------------------
# Let us make a random array with number of NaN values n_nans 
A=np.random.random((nz,ny,nz))
i_nan=np.array(np.random.random((n_nans))*npts,dtype='int32')
dum = A.flatten();
dum[i_nan] = np.nan;
A=np.reshape(dum,np.shape(A))
# ----------------------------

A_nanmask=np.zeros(np.shape(A));A_nanmask[np.isnan(A)]=1;
A_notnanmask=np.ones(np.shape(A));A_notnanmask[np.isnan(A)]=0;
# -----------------------------
# Get some count of nans:
A_notnan = np.sum(A_notnanmask,axis=0)
A_nan = np.sum(A_nanmask,axis=0)

# Check the sums:
A_total = A_notnan+A_nan
```

So, the A_total should be 50 in this example.